# Values are not shown on ng-repeat template, but only on localhost apparently

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code to dynamically fill an array in my $scope:

```
var mapApp = angular.module('mapApp', []);

mapApp.controller('MapController', function($scope) {

  $scope.establishments = [];

  function removeMarkers() {
    for (var x = markers.length - 1; x == 0; x--)
      markers[x].setMap(null);

    markers.length = 0;
    $scope.establishments.length = 0;
  }

  function onMapCenterChanged() {



    $.getJSON('https://api.....', function(data) {
      if (data) {
        $('#json').text(JSON.stringify(data));
        if (data.response) {
          removeMarkers();

          $.each(data.response.groups[0].items, function(index, row) {

            var venue = {
              name: row.venue.name,
              address: row.venue.location.address,
              rating: row.venue.rating,
              price: row.venue.price.tier
            };

            $scope.establishments.push(venue);
          });

          // DO I REALLY NEED TO CALL THIS?
          $scope.$apply()
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

});
```

And I'm using this code to display the establishments array:

```
<li ng-repeat="venue in establishments">
    <span>{{ venue.name }}</span>
    <p>{{ venue.address }}</p>
    <p>Price: {{ venue.price }} - Rating: {{ venue.rating }}</p>
</li>
```

However, I'm only getting a list like this:

- Price: - Rating:
- Price: - Rating:
- Price: - Rating:

Why is not working? And why do I need to call the apply method when adding items to arrays in my scope?

### UPDATE

If I check the value of `$scope.establishments` after `$scope.$apply();`, all values are there. But, if I place a `{{ establishments }}` in my HTML, it doesn't show anything.

### UPDATE 2

I've made a test copying the entire code to jsfiddle and it works (everything is printed). The version running on localhost runs without any error (on Chrome Developer Tools), but the items in the array are not printed.

Here is the [jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/julianonunes/bkhyf8gd/) with the complete code.

Comment: dump out establishments array before your list and see if you're doing something weird `{{ establishments }}`

Comment: $scope.$apply() is required whenever the data changes outside of the angular and to let, angular know the changes by initiating $digest cycle.

Comment: The data is changed inside the controller but still if I don't use the apply the length of the array stays at 0.

Comment: @JulianoNunesSilvaOliveira Whether your issue is resolved or not after implementing the Amar Duplantier answer ?

Comment: Are you sure your json object is correct ? The keys in the json object should be string type. Should be something like : var venue = {"name" : row.venue.name, ........};

Comment: Did changing `$scope.establishments.length = 0;` to `$scope.establishments = [];` work?

Comment: It didn't work, @AmarDuplantier. And changing the keys to strings didn't work too.

Comment: @Vaibhav The json keys don't have to be strings...

Comment: FYI: I had to call $scope.$apply() because I was making a request to the service and looping through the results via jQuery. After replacing them by $http.get and angular.forEach, the $apply() isn't necessary anymore. But, it still doesn't display the values in my objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's the real problem and the solution.

I'm working on a Python/Django project which also uses the curly braces ({{ }}) for templates, so they were conflicting.

The solution is to replace the curly braces by ng-bind.